# How to do asyncrhonous jQuery.get() before $(window).load()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I want a SVG file to be loaded in a variable before $(window).load() will be fired.

I load the file using jQuery.get(). The problem is, that this function works asynchronously and by the time, when the SVG file is read, the $(window).load() is already invoked.

So I have following code:

```
var data;

$(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery.get(
        "my.svg",
        function (_data) {
            data = _data;
        },
        'text');
});


$(window).load( function () {
    alert(data);
});
```

The alert will show "undefined". If it will be invoked later (after 5 seconds for example) then it will show the content of the SVG file.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Using this method, it will require a `setInterval` and a conditional statement checking the contents of `data`.

Comment: You can force a synchronous request. Or use setInterval.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that setInterval would probably be the solution you want IF you want to do stuff the hard way because you can never tell how long an AJAX request is going to take.

I would recommend restructuring your code to be more like this:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function () {

    //this can remain async: TRUE
    jQuery.get(
        "my.svg",
        function (_data) {

            //call function to do something to svg file
            //if you are relying on the SVG to be there in order to call an action
            //then why not wait for the SVG to load first and then call the action
            svgAction(_data);

        },
        'text');

    function svgAction(img_code){
        //do something with img code now
    }

});

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! I agree that it is definitely better than setInterval(). But this approach is quite complex. Especially if multiple SVG-files must be preloaded. I was hoping for some easy solution :-)

Comment: Glad I could help! This is the easy solution by the way...Also I don't see where multiple SVGs were mentioned/hinted in the original question. You should probably start a new question for that.